# Setting a global variable within a function

Tags: javascript, initialization, global-variables, scope

What I want to do is initialize a global variable outside of a function, set the variable within the function, and then print the variables value after the function. When I print however, it logs out `No Message Provided`.

In this case, I'm attempting to do this with the itemLocation variable.

```
var itemLocation;
Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function (request, response) {
    url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: url,
        params: {
            'OPERATION-NAME': 'findItemsByKeywords',
                'SERVICE-VERSION': '1.12.0',
                'SECURITY-APPNAME': '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
                'GLOBAL-ID': 'EBAY-US',
                'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
                'itemFilter(0).name=ListingType': 'itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice',
                'keywords': request.params.item,
        },
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            // parses results
            var httpresponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
            var items = [];
            httpresponse.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.forEach(function (itemByKeywordsResponse) {
                itemByKeywordsResponse.searchResult.forEach(function (result) {
                    result.item.forEach(function (item) {
                        items.push(item);
                    });
                });
            });


            // count number of times each unique primaryCategory shows up (based on categoryId), returns top two IDs and their respective names
            var categoryIdResults = {};

            // Collect two most frequent categoryIds
            items.forEach(function (item) {
                var id = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryId;
                if (categoryIdResults[id]) categoryIdResults[id]++;
                else categoryIdResults[id] = 1;
            });

            var top2 = Object.keys(categoryIdResults).sort(function (a, b) {
                return categoryIdResults[b] - categoryIdResults[a];
            }).slice(0, 2);
            console.log('Top category Ids: ' + top2.join(', '));

            var categoryNameResults = {};

            // Collect two most frequent categoryNames  
            items.forEach(function (item) {
                var categoryName = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryName;
                if (categoryNameResults[categoryName]) categoryNameResults[categoryName]++;
                else categoryNameResults[categoryName] = 1;
            });

            var top2Names = Object.keys(categoryNameResults).sort(function (a, b) {
                return categoryNameResults[b] - categoryNameResults[a];
            }).slice(0, 2);
            console.log('Top category Names: ' + top2Names.join(', '));

            // compare categoryIdResults to userCategory object
            //Extend the Parse.Object class to make the userCategory class
            var userCategory = Parse.Object.extend("userCategory");

            //Use Parse.Query to generate a new query, specifically querying the userCategory object.
            query = new Parse.Query(userCategory);

            //Set constraints on the query.
            query.containedIn('categoryId', top2);
            query.equalTo('parent', Parse.User.current())

            //Submit the query and pass in callback functions.
            var isMatching = false;
            query.find({
                success: function (results) {
                    var userCategoriesMatchingTop2 = results;
                    console.log("userCategory comparison success!");
                    console.log(results);

                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        itemCondition = results[i].get("itemCondition");
                        console.log(itemCondition);

                        itemLocation = results[i].get("itemLocation");
                        console.log(itemLocation);

                        minPrice = results[i].get("minPrice");
                        console.log(minPrice);

                        maxPrice = results[i].get("maxPrice");
                        console.log(maxPrice);

                        itemSearch = request.params.item;
                        console.log(itemSearch);
                    }

                    if (userCategoriesMatchingTop2 && userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length > 0) {
                        isMatching = true;
                    }

                    response.success({
                        "results": [{
                            "Number of top categories": top2.length
                        }, {
                            "Top category Ids": top2
                        }, {
                            "Top category names": top2Names
                        }, {
                            "Number of matches": userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length
                        }, {
                            "User categories that match search": userCategoriesMatchingTop2
                        }, {
                            "Matching Category Condition": itemCondition
                        }, {
                            "Matching Category Location": itemLocation
                        }, {
                            "Matching Category MaxPrice": maxPrice
                        }, {
                            "Matching Category MinPrice": minPrice
                        }, {
                            "Search Term": itemSearch
                        },

                        ]
                    });
                    console.log('User categories that match search: ', results);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //Error Callback
                    console.log("An error has occurred");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log('error!!!');
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
});
console.log(itemLocation);
```

Comment: Can you eliminate all the code that isn't needed so you have the bare minimum that reproduces the problem?

Also, I am assuming that you are using requireJS due to the "define" method.  Is that true, or is define one of your own constructs?  If it is true, do you have a way to confirm that the eBayCategorySearch dependency is resolved?

Comment: this seems to happen because of async behavior of `httpRequest`, the way you need to do is, either passing callbacks or using promises.

Comment: @PatViafore, the define method is part of Parse.com's documentation.

Comment: @code-jaff could you provide an example of what you mean? Are you saying that because this function is an httpRequest, it clears any variable assignments when the function is done?

Comment: @user3561379 I actually don't know anything about [`parse`](https://parse.com), but it seems the `define` creates a controller and responsible for a specific request. Then what is the need of getting the variable outside of that controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve, but this is *one way* to do what you suppose to do.

```
var itemLocation;
var promise; // variable holding the promise
Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function (request, response) {
    url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
    // set the promise
    promise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        // your code goes here (setting the variables)
    });
});

// once the promise has been resolved
promise.then(function(resp){
    console.log(itemLocation);
});
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error when attempting to deploy to Parse stating `The error was TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined`, referring to `promise.then(function(resp){
    console.log(itemLocation);
});`